# Adjusting a $y = \sin(x)$ graph slightly

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a function where

$$ y = m\sin\Bigl(\frac{x^{1.1}+30}{0.7d}\Bigr)^{2.2} $$
where $m = 45$ and $d = 120$ (constants)

I would like the turning point at the top of the sin curve to peak at 0.75d (90). I would like the starting and finishing values to remain the same.

The current function is plotted in blue. I would like a line similar to the red one. Feel free to ditch the sin function, if another method would be better

[image: imagen]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try with $a x^\alpha$, adjusting $a$ so that $a x^\alpha=x^{1.1}$ at the endpoint.

Comment: If you're hoping to have some sort of periodicity, you might just play around with summing $\sin(x), \sin(2x), \sin(3x), \ldots$ in various proportions; for instance, $\sin(x)-\sin(2x)$ looks a lot like what you want on $[0,\pi]$ (although the peak is at 2/3 of the length for that one)

Comment: Thanks Milo, I agree with keeping some sort of periodicity. How could I keep where my max values, which constant m is currently doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the curve $$y=\frac{(x-4)^4}{12}-\frac{kx^2}{2}+cx+d,$$ where the constants are given by $d=5-\frac{90^4}{12}$ and $$240=2×30^4-12k(120^2)+24(120c)+24d,\\2M=2d+180c-8100k,$$ with $M$ being the maximum value you want the function to attain.

Comment: Thanks. I understand points (1) and (2), I am struggling to grapple with the mathematics of your final expression. Would you mind writing it in the format of y = ...   . Furthermore, wouldn’t an (x-90)^2 function lose all its periodicity. I.e. a deceleration to the turning point and acceleration from the turning point and max gradient to be found between turning points.

Comment: @Ollie But you didn't include periodicity among the properties you wanted. In fact, the original function isn't periodic at all.

Comment: @Ollie The final expression is already in the form $y=\cdots.$

Comment: Maybe I have the wrong word for it. I would like still like the qualities of the deceleration and acceleration away from the graph turning points, which is seen in sine, cosine styled functions. Parabolic. functions do not have this quality as they are not trigonometric.

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t understand this expression: “with ,>0
a, A>0 and −8100=(0) A−8100=g(0) and −900=(120)A−900=g(120)and A being the maximum value”

Comment: @Ollie Are you talking about the way the curve bends downwards, then upwards, then downwards again?

Comment: I suppose so. What I mean is that the curve doesn’t decelerate and accelerate at a constant rate. Differentiating the curve leaves another trigonometric function, rather than a constant.

Comment: @Ollie Oh, what I meant is that $a$ and $A$ are both positive numbers chosen so that the value of the function when $x=0$ is equal to $A-8100$ and the value at the endpoint where $x=120$ is equal to $A-900.$ For this to happen we must have $g(120)=g(0)+7200.$

Comment: @Ollie Well, I thought you said the sine function could be ditched? If all you want is any curve that bends like the given curve above, then that can be done in many ways. It need not be a sine curve. But of course, a parabola doesn't bend that way. I didn't know you wanted such a condition to be fulfilled as well. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Ollie I've got a curve that may satisfy all requirements so far. However, I need to clarify: Should the difference $g(120)-g(0)=5$ as is implied in the graph above?

Comment: yes please. thank you

Comment: @Ollie Hump! Then it will not work. I was thinking of $$y=\frac{M}{1+(x-90)^2},$$ but I will look further into this problem!

Comment: Thanks for your help. If there is a solution which is roughly correct, I would be interested ub that too. Thank you

Comment: @Ollie OK, I think I've found a curve which satisfies all your conditions so far (except for implicit ones we may not know yet). So consider the curve $$y=\frac{(x-4)^4}{12}-\frac{kx^2}{2}+cx+d,$$ where the constants are given by $d=5-\frac{90^4}{12}$ and $$240=2×30^4-12k(120^2)+24(120c)+24d,\,2M=2d+180c-8100k,$$ and $M$ is the maximum value you want the function to attain.

Comment: Many thanks for this.

Comment: @Ollie Welcome. Glad it helped!